# HTML not applying external styling

Tags: html, css, localhost

I am trying to practice some web development with a simple HTML file and some external styling. I have my HTML and CSS files saved in the same folder, and am attempting to link the CSS to my HTML file. When I go to view the page, none of the styling is applied. There is a file called "styles.css" loaded into the sources tab, but it just looks like my HTML file. The HTML included is from the file I want to link by the name of the file in the sources. You can see the link attempt (I've tried with and without specifying type, and I've tried putting a slash in front of the name of the file), and you can see the file included in sources:

[image: not a css file]

I've looked at each element, I've looked at the computed styles, and nothing suggests that the file is properly loaded. I've looked through several questions and most of the solutions are things I've already tried. Thanks!

Comment: I downloaded and installed an extension for VS Code called Live Server. When I run that, it updates the files in the sources tab. This is what I was expecting. Seems to be working now. Not sure why localhost isn't working if I generate the page from js.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/20d7F.png

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the index file is saved as a .html file.
If it's still not working try href="./styles.css"

Answer (score 0):

try writing  href="./style.css"